# Disable editing a *.tmp file by default?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I just need to edit on the original file, not in a `.tmp` file  using Aptana.

On that way Aptana does not respect UTF-8.

This happen when the Aptana automatically update to 3.0. I uninstalled, and delete manually all residual folders. Then install 2.5 and the iussue persist :(

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

try to use correct html5 declaration `<html></html>` and `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: Thank you Borkie but the issue is on Aptana, not in HTML :(

Comment: So try under Edit->Set Encoding and set to UTF-8

Comment: Thank you Borkie. Finally i install Aptana in a new PC, and everything works better. :)